# Show that $Y_n$ converges in probability

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

[image]

I attempted part ii of the question with the following:

To show that $Y_n$ converges in probability, I started off with $P(|Y_n-0|>\epsilon$). I then wrote, for $0<\epsilon<\theta$

$P(Y_n<-\epsilon).$ However, trying to evaulate this lead me nowhere. Upon looking at the solutions:
[image]

It says that $P(Y_n>\epsilon)$. Why is this so? How do I know that $Y_n$ is positive?

Comment: $Y_n$ is the smallest of a bunch of positive numbers.

Answer (score 4):

For $0<y<\theta$ and $n\geqslant1$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y_n>y) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i>y\} \right)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(X_i>y)\\
&=\mathbb P(X_1>y)^n\\
&=\left(1-\frac y\theta\right)^n,
\end{align}
from which $$F_{Y_n}(y)= 1-\left(1-\frac y\theta\right)^n $$
and
$$f_{Y_n}(y) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy}F_{Y_n}(y) = \frac n\theta\left(1-\frac y\theta\right)^{n-1}. $$

Since $Y_n\geqslant 0$ almost surely, we may compute the expectation by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y_n] &= \int_0^\theta \mathbb P(Y_n>y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^\theta \left(1-\frac y\theta\right)^n\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \theta\int_0^1 u^n \ \mathsf du\\
&= \frac\theta{n+1}.
\end{align}
Since $\mathbb E[Y_n]\stackrel{n\to\infty}0$, we see that $Y_n\to0$ in $L^1$, and hence converges to zero in probability as well.

Answer (score 0):

i

To get $f_Y(y)$, let's compute $F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y)$ then differentiate $F_Y(y)$.

Note that $P(Y \le y) = 1 - P(Y > y)$.

If we have $Y = \min\{X_1, \cdots, X_n\}$, then $$Y > y \iff X_1 > y, X_2 > y, \cdots X_n > y$$

Thus

$$P(Y > y) = P(X_1 > y, X_2 > y, \cdots X_n > y)$$

$$= P(X_1 > y)P(X_2 > y) \cdots P(X_n > y)$$

$$= [1-P(X_1 \le y)][1-P(X_2 \le y)] \cdots [1-P(X_n \le y)]$$

$$= [1-P(X_1 \le y)]^n$$

$$= [1-\int_{0}^{y} \frac{1}{\theta-0} dx_1]^n$$

$$= [1-\frac{y}{\theta}]^n$$

$$\to F_Y(y) = 1 - [1-\frac{y}{\theta}]^n$$

$$\to f_Y(y) = -n[1-\frac{y}{\theta}]^{n-1}(-\frac{1}{\theta})$$

$$\to f_Y(y) = n[1-\frac{y}{\theta}]^{n-1}(\frac{1}{\theta})$$

ii

$$P(|Y_n - 0| > \varepsilon) = P(|Y_n| > \varepsilon)$$

$$= P(Y_n > \varepsilon)$$

$$ = 1 - P(Y_n \le \varepsilon)$$

Now let's use i:

$$P(Y_n \le \varepsilon) = F_{Y_n}(\varepsilon) = 1 - [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}]^n$$

$$\to \lim_{n \to \infty} P(Y_n \le \varepsilon) = \lim_{n \to \infty} [1 - [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}]^n]$$

$$ =  1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}]^n$$

$$ =  1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}]^n$$

$$= 1 - 0 \tag{*}$$

$$= 1$$

Why $(*)$?

Well

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}]^n = 0 \iff -1 < 1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta} < 1$$

We obviously have $$1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta} < 1$$

Next up: $$-1 < 1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta} \iff 2\theta > \varepsilon$$

Actually, $$\theta > \varepsilon > 0$$

Why?

In the first place, the formula $$F_{Y_n}(\varepsilon) = 1 - [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}]^n$$ is for $0 < \varepsilon < \theta$

Hopefully, it's clear that

1. $$F_{Y_n}(\theta) = 1$$
2. $$F_{Y_n}(0) = 0$$
3. $$F_{Y_n}(\varepsilon) = 1 \ \text{if} \ \varepsilon > \theta$$
4. $$F_{Y_n}(\varepsilon) = 0 \ \text{if} \ \varepsilon < 0$$

P.S. I hope it's clear why $Y_n > 0$ (a.s.):

$$Y_n = \min\{X_1, \cdots X_n\} = \min\{\text{positive a.s.}, \text{positive a.s.}, \cdots, \text{positive a.s.}\} = \text{positive a.s.}$$